# Update ActiveRecord (associations included) without saving it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a simple way to update all attributes (associations included) of an ActiveRecord without saving it (neither associations)?

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController 
... 
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  # THE MAGIC HAPPENS HERE

  respond_to do |format|
   if @post.save
     format.html { redirect_to roles_path }
   else
     format.html { render 'edit' }
   end
 ... 
end
```

The code above is a simplified version of what I'm dealing right now but if the solution works here it works also in my case.

Thanks and have a nice day.

UPDATE
The solution proposed in the duplicated (`assign_attributes`) does not work with associations. See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17368) and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference-when-are-objects-saved-questionmark).

Comment: @GokulM OP is right, this is not a duplicate... assign_attributes saves associations.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Ok, I agree. I removed it.